# TFS 2008: Does it come with a license for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

When you buy TFS 2008, you get a license to run SQL Server 2005 as the data repository for TFS.

With SP1 of TFS 2008, SQL Server 2008 is now supported. Does any one know if the TFS 2008 license allows us to install SQL Server 2008 instead of SQL Server 2005?

Are there any advantages using SQL Server 2008 over SQl Server 2005 as the database for TFS 2008 (other than the reduction in pain for a later upgrade)?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: I have no problem closing this question. But I do have take issue with closing questions based on rules made after the question was posted. The answer referred here was made in 2014.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no license for SQL 2008 and will require a separate license to install.  Interestingly enough, if you run your data tier on another server, you require a separate SQL license anyway as if you want to use the SQL license that comes with TFS, it has to run on the application tier.

[More info.](http://internationalized.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!43F3A7682D1564E4!972.entry)

From the advantages point, SQL 2008 reporting services is much improved, the general speed and query plan enhancements does make it a viable option and will be more performant.

Comment: Can I get a link to a document that specifically says that SQL Server 2008 license is provided/not provided?

Comment: Hi Rajah I have no link but this is from comms I have received.

Comment: Here is a link to the TFS 2008 licensing whitepaper but unfortunately excludes SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=CE194742-A6E8-4126-AA30-5C4E969AF2A3&displaylang=en

Comment: Hi - This is based on information I received from Microsoft directly (link is to my blog :))  The whitepaper also spells it out (not an easy read)

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add - and you can get this from the whitepaper - a Team Foundation Server license includes the provision of "A restricted-use version of SQL Server Standard Edition is included with Team Foundation Server, which is installed separately.".

However, as Ray has pointed out - it's for **SQL Server 2005**.  AFAIK this hasn't been updated with the release of Service Pack 1.

Edit: Checked with a contact @ Microsoft - the license was not updated with Service Pack 1 (though it was considered).  In other words, a separate SKU for SQL Server 2008 can be purchased and used with TFS, but the Restricted Use SQL license attached to the TFS license remains only for SQL Server 2005 (which is shipped as part of the TFS product materials).

As to the advantages of SQL 2008 with TFS - It's all about BI.  There have been complete refactoring of the Analysis Services, Reporting and Integration services so you can do a lot more with regard to reporting on TFS data.

There are some Database Engine changes (such as compression) but nothing I'd really think of that is an integral upgrade over 2005 (in the TFS context).

Hope it helps..
Rob